# Launch a completely independent process

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, fork, child-process

I want to initiate a process from my python script `main.py`. Specifically, I want to run the below command:

```
`nohup python ./myfile.py &`
```

and the file `myfile.py` should continue running, even after the `main.py` script exits.

I also wish to get the `pid` of the new process.

I tried:

- `os.spawnl*`
- `os.exec*`
- `subprocess.Popen`

and all are terminating the `myfile.py` when the `main.py` script exits.

---

**Update:** Can I use `os.startfile` with `xdg-open`? Is it the right approach?

---

**Example**

```
a = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "nohup /usr/bin/python25 /long_process.py &"],\
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print a.pid
```

If I check `ps aux | grep long_process`, there is no process running.

**long_process.py** which keeps on printing some text: no exit.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that fails to work? After a trivial `python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "60"])'` the output of `ps` shows that the `sleep` keeps running just fine after Python has exited.

Comment: You are running Python with a single argument, `"nohup /usr/bin/python25 ..."`, which cannot work because the `python` executable will look for a script in a file named exactly `nohup /usr/bin/...`, which doesn't exist. And since you specify `stderr` as `PIPE` without ever reading the pipe's content, you never get to see the error message. Lose the `nohup` and `&`, and simply run `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/.../long_process.py"])`. Also, don't specify `stdin` and `stderr` as pipes unless you mean it.

Comment: `nohup` makes most sense when you start a process from a shell. I don't see `shell=True` in your `Popen` call.

Comment: Very related question: [subprocess - Run a program from python, and have it continue to run after the script is killed - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille/16928558#16928558)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You open your long-running process and *keep a pipe to it*. So you expect to talk to it. When yor launcher script exits, you can no longer talk to it. <s>The long-running process receives a `SIGPIPE` and exits.</s>

The following just worked for me (Linux, Python 2.7).

Create a long-running executable:

```
$ echo "sleep 100" > ~/tmp/sleeper.sh
```

Run Python REPL:

```
$ python
>>>

import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/sleeper.sh')])
# look ma, no pipes!
print p.pid
# prints 29893
```

Exit the REPL and see the process still running:

```
>>> ^D
$ ps ax | grep sleeper
29893 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/sh .../tmp/sleeper.sh
29917 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto sleeper
```

If you want to first communicate to the started process and then leave it alone to run further, you have a few options:

- Handle `SIGPIPE` in your long-running process, do not die on it. Live without stdin after the launcher process exits.
- Pass whatever you wanted using arguments, environment, or a temporary file.
- If you want bidirectional communication, consider using a named pipe ([man mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo)) or a socket, or writing a proper server.
- Make the long-running process fork after the initial bi-direcional communication phase is done.

Comment: Great answer, it's a good point that the process dies due to `SIGPIPE`. (In the code from the question the process never got started, but the OP might have also tried other variants that did start and died due to `SIGPIPE`.)

Comment: It does not create "a completely independent process" (that what `python-daemon` package does). Also, [a child process won't get SIGPIPE in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22083141/4279). Though in simple cases, your solution is enough (you should redirect to `os.devnull` child's stdin/stdout/stderr to avoid waiting for input and/or a spurious output to the terminal).

Comment: @user4815162342: It won't die due to SIGPIPE in Python 2 (the question has [tag:python2.7] tag).

Comment: here's an example of why the redirection is important: it may allow a parent process to exit before its child finished writing its output: [Python subprocess .check_call vs .check_output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36169571/4279)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `os.fork()`.

```
import os
pid=os.fork()
if pid==0: # new process
    os.system("nohup python ./myfile.py &")
    exit()
# parent process continues
```

Comment: Note that `os.fork()` [does not exist for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300551/how-to-run-python-script-with-os-fork-on-windows)

Comment: Using `nohup` here is pointless. It does exactly two things: (1) disabling HUP propagation, which is **already** turned off for noninteractive shells and so doesn't need to be further disabled; and (2) redirecting stdin, stdout and stderr if they're attached to the terminal (which you can do yourself trivially; `</dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1` and you just did the exact same redirections nohup would do). Much more efficient to just leave all the shells out of it entirely, as the answer by @jfs does.

Answer (score 9):

> I could not see any process running.

You don't see any process running because the child `python` process exits immediately. The `Popen` arguments are incorrect as [user4815162342 says in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624850/launch-a-completely-independent-process#comment43670640_27624850).

To launch  a *completely independent* process, you could use [`python-daemon` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) or use systemd/supervisord/etc:

```
#!/usr/bin/python25
import daemon
from long_process import main

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    main()
```

Though it might be enough in your case, to start the child with correct `Popen` arguments:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0) as DEVNULL:
    p = Popen(['/usr/bin/python25', '/path/to/long_process.py'],
              stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
time.sleep(1) # give it a second to launch
if p.poll(): # the process already finished and it has nonzero exit code
    sys.exit(p.returncode)
```

If the child process doesn't require `python2.5` then you could use `sys.executable` instead (to use the same Python version as the parent).

Note: the code closes `DEVNULL` in the parent without waiting for the child process to finish (it has no effect on the child).