# Python spawn detatched non-python process on linux?

Tags: python, subprocess, launcher, detach, platform-independent

I was to make a launcher application, I haven't found a way to detach a sub-process entirely from the spawning python process.

When I launch a program with my desktop's (cinnamon's) launcher the process tree goes:

> <kbd>/sbin/init</kbd> -> <kbd>mdm</kbd> -> <kbd>mdm</kbd> -> <kbd>cinnamon-session</kbd> -> <kbd>cinnamon</kbd> -> <kbd>the-app-i-launched</kbd>

Of the threads I read, this one was the most insightful/helpful: [Launch a completely independent process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27624850/1695680). But gets muddied answers as the OP is looking to run python code, which can often be achieved in many usually-preferred ways than by spawning an independent process.

From other posts from stack overflow that do not answer how to launch a detatched python process:

- [Running daemonalized python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772954/1695680): Applicable to running *python code/module* as a daemon, (not another process/application) detached from the python instance.
- [subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204049/1695680): Process spawns as a child of the python process.
- [os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204017/1695680): Process spawns as a child of the python process.
- [close_fds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593715/1695680): (Apparently) Windows(R)-only solution, need portable solution (primary target is Debian linux). Attempting to use `close_fds=True` on linux, process spawns as a child of the python process.
- [creationflags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593334/1695680): Windows(R)-only solution. On linux raises: `ValueError: creationflags is only supported on Windows platforms`.
- [prefix launched process with `nohup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661632/1695680): Process spawns as a child of the python process. As far as I know, `nohup` or equivalent is not available on all platforms, making it a linux-only solution.
- [os.fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972383/1695680): Same as "Running daemonalized python code".
- [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972963/1695680): Same *problem* as "Running daemonalized python code": useful only for running python code/module.
- [os.spawnl* + os.P_NOWAIT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/972362/1695680): Deprecated functions are undesirable to use for new code. In my testing I was not able to see my process actually spawned at all.
- [os.spawnl* + os.P_DETACH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196122/1695680):  Windows(R)-only, seemingly removed in current python 2.X versions: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'P_DETACH'.`
- [os.system + shell fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196112/1695680): I was able to actually see my process run detatched from the python process with this, however I am woried that it has the faults:

  - Relies on running commands in a shell, which is more vulnerable to maliciousness, intentional or otherwise<sup>?</sup>.
  - Relies on non-portable<sup>?</sup> POSIX/shell<sup>?</sup> syntaxies that may not be interpenetrate on non-Linux platforms. Which I haven't dug up any good reference for portability on <sup>[Partial Ref](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand)</sup>.
- [subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27625288/1695680) <sup>[Alt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30915818/1695680)</sup>: I still only observed the sub-process running as a child of the python process.

Comment: i think the question i was trying to ask is "how to disown a process" and I'm not sure there is really a way to disown a process completely, at best it can maybe be owned by the spawning process's parent process. My objective was to run a process that could survive after the launching process closed, I think the only viable option is to host that process from a daemon meant to host other processes, i think most shells, including desktop shells, own this responsibility which is why "using bash" seemed like a viable option. albeit somewhat a confusing mess.  Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution can be found in JonMc's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille/16928558#16928558). I use it to open documents using 'xdg-open'.

You can change the stderr argument to `stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'),` if you do not want a logfile.

Answer (score -1):

The only workable solution I have, and that may be non-portable Linux-only is to use shell evaluation with shell-detach-ampersand syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os

os.system('{cmd} &'.format('firefox'))
```

This might go too-far up the process tree though, outside of the window manager session, potentially not-exiting with your desktop session.

> <kbd>/sbin/init</kbd> -> <kbd>firefox</kbd>

Comment: I think this way the process is not detached.