# How do I call a function after using 'webbrowser.get()' in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-webbrowser

The problem
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("http://"+where.strip())

```
    main()
```

I want to call main() while the browser is still open however it only runs after closing the browser,how do I fix that?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to do? You would need to use two processes running along side each other. Otherwise in a linear Python script you have to wait for the last code-block to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open the browser as a new process and create a pipe for the data to flow between. There is a wonderful Stack Overflow topic that already covers this topic for Python; please check it out here:

[Launch a completely independent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624850/launch-a-completely-independent-process)