# Flask spawning indepenent process (fork) leads to port in use

Tags: python, c++, flask, fork

I would like to let a independent C++ process be called by Flask and Flask should keep on running.
It starts the c++ process and if I kill Flask it keeps on running (good).
My problem is, if I re-start Flask, it will say port in use running and I can't relaunch. So it seems that this process still somehow relates to Flask. How can avoid this?
Thanks

```
import os
pid=os.fork()
if pid==0: # new process
    os.system("nohup /path/myc++ &")
```

[Launch a completely independent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624850/launch-a-completely-independent-process)

**Error:**

```
sudo python server.py 
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1046, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 795, in run_simple
    s.bind(get_sockaddr(hostname, port, address_family))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: I believe if you shut down workzeug the port should reopen. http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/

What you probably actually want is a message queue, like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ, which can pass data to totally separate processes.

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)` I use and then I press Strg+C in console.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your child process (myc++) inherited all file opened descriptors (socket included) from the parent (Flask) after the `fork()` call. When the parent process exits, these descriptors remain in opened stats and at the next launch, Flask would be unable to bind a socket at an already opened port.

After the fork, in the child process, parent file descriptors must be closed before the `system()` command starts.

You should try this code :

```
    import os
    pid=os.fork()
    if pid==0: # new process
            for fd in xrange(0, 1024):
                try:
                    os.close(fd)
                except OSError:
                    pass
            os.system("nohup /path/myc++ &")
```