# rails line chart chartkick display the last year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linechart, chartkick

[image]This chart doesnt show me all the cases for all the years, it just show me the cases in the last year 2023.
How can I display all the cases for all the years?

```
<%= line_chart Case.all.group_by_year(:created_at).count,
        stacked: true,
        xtitle: "Date",
        ytitle: "Transactions",
        # Additions I've tried:
        library: {
        format: 'MM/YY'
        },
        discrete: true %>
```

Answer (score -2):

To display all the cases for all the years in your chart, you can modify your code as follows:

```rb
<%= line_chart Case.group_by_year(:created_at),
        library: {
          xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
              format: '{value: %m/%y}'
            }
          }
        },
        xtitle: "Date",
        ytitle: "Transactions",
        discrete: true %>
```

It's because you're passing count of records to the chartkik. Can you pass Case.all.group_by_year(:created_at) without count instead?

Comment: It is still the same, check the updated picture for how it looks

Comment: Please note that the use of AI tools continues to be banned here. You've posted several answers which appear likely to have been aided (entirely or partially) by AI. If you used an AI tool to assist in this answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: For readers of this answer, please validate the answer carefully and comment with any errors. Users who post low-quality information from AI may be suspended, and the moderation team could use your help identifying issues in the post (if any). However, please do not downvote the answer based on my comment - Only if you can individually confirm issues with it.

Comment: @nourza I think it's because you're passing count of records to the chartkik. Can you pass Case.all.group_by_year(:created_at) instead

Comment: @nourza And if it doesn't help, can please also show an example of what contains here Case.all.group_by_year(:created_at)

Comment: @sapiv71097 this is the result of <%= Case.all.group_by_year(:created_at).count %> {Sun, 01 Jan 2023=>26}

Comment: As I said, *likely* and *if*, and I notice that you don't actually claim not to be using AI, just claiming that I can't tell ;-).  Just fair warning for you.  I checked with several Mods before posting these comments, and they felt that it was appropriate to warn users who appear to be using AI.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds what's AI?

Comment: @nourza Artificial Intelligence (e.g., ChatGPT).  It's unfortunately far too common for ChatGPT (and other AI) answers to have errors, so for that reason they are [currently banned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11810933).  Personally, I'll say that I support the [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710), but until that's the case, it's still against the rules.  Of course, us puny humans can make mistakes as well, but AI sure makes some big ones at the moment ;-).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds can people make mistakes in answers and how to differ AI mistakes from peoples'?

Comment: @sapiv71097 If a user repeatedly posts answers that are low-quality, then it really doesn't matter whether they are AI-generated or the user's own mistakes -- There are both automated and Moderator tools in place to reprimand the user.  Personally, I support the [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) here on SE.  But unvalidated GPT/AI output is, obviously, problematic.  Since it is difficult to tell the difference, the community here on SO has chosen to ban *all* GPT use.

Comment: I do not publicly share the multiple methods I use to detect potential AI content, because we unfortunately have a small group of users who actively try to obscure the fact that they are using AI.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds cool down, everything is ok and just stop stalking me

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds it's so sad. Maybe you partially or entirely used here AI ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866319/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-fork-while-using-ubuntu-bash-from/65866548#65866548
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349462/how-to-recover-lost-20-04-1-0-administrative-password-on-wsl-windows-subsystem/1349636#1349636
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443572/how-to-get-the-ip-address-without-ifconfig-or-ip-command-in-ubuntu/1443606#1443606

Comment: Oh, that is just too funny. Accusing @NotTheDr01ds of  using AI *before* AI was even available. I have to save this comment thread for future reference as it is just too precious!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do you know what's really funny? That somebody cleaning up my answers to you. I believe that somebody protects you from me

Comment: @sapiv71097 group_by_month on phone screen it display just the first four months

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?